# Adobe AIR: online/offline database sync

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am working on an AIR app which should work in both online and offline model. The user can do various actions, while offline and the results would get saved in a local DB. The same needs to get synced up with the global DB once the user goes online. I googled a bit on it, and it seems that Adobe LCDS (lifecycle data services) is the only available option to do it. However, it is an enterprise solution, and way too costly.

Is there any other implementation for this? Has anyone used CouchDB for online/offline synchronization?

Thanks and Regards,
Kapil Kaushik

Comment: What about WebOrb? http://www.themidnightcoders.com/develop-ria/guided-tour.html

Comment: So far as I know you can only use SQLite for local database storage with AIR.  As far as communicating with the server, you can use WebOrb like DennisJaamann recommended, there is also [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS), or you can roll your own solution with something link [ZendAMF](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Amf+-+Wade+Arnold) or [RocketAMF](http://rubygems.org/gems/RocketAMF).

Comment: Hi Dennis.....thanks for your comments. I checked out WebOrb, and it surely looks promising. I'll try to create a prototype to understand it better...thanks again !!

Comment: Hi NoobsArePeople2.....communicating with server is not the issue I am trying to solve here. As you mentioned, there are plenty of ways to do that. The problem I am trying to solve is database sync b/w application and server. I have done some little work with BlazeDS....but will surely checkout ZendAMF and RocketAMF...thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For doing a DB sync with your server when the Air app is only, you *do not have any requirements as for which backend technology you use*.  LCDS makes it *simpler*, but it's not your only option.  Heck, you could use just a normal PHP script to do the sync for you if you'd like.

The hard part of it all is that you need to figure out your syncing algorithm so that you don't lose any information.  Normally what I do is that when the app is connected online again, it sends all the information that was modified/create (with timestamps on when it was modified) while offline to the server, then the server has an algorithm that checks if the offline information is newer than what was done previous (or does some other business rule depending on your situation).  When the server decides which data is good, it then sends the updated data to the client and effectively syncs everything.

This can be done through a normal HTTP request, polling or pushing.

Comment: Hi J_A_X.....thanks for your response. I understand that it is definitely doable....but as you said the hard part is the syncing algorithm. From what I have read till now, this is a fairly non-trivial task. So, I was looking for an easier option. Couch DB seems to take care of the synchronization part automatically...so I am trying to understand whether it fits the bill !!